# subfigure in sivp journal

Tags: latex, figure

in SIVP journal latex template there is an example like this

```
\begin{figure}
\resizebox{0.3\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics*{Images/Introduction/l14.eps}}
\resizebox{0.3\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics*{Images/Introduction/l14.seg.eps}}
\caption{Imperfect segmentation in variable illumination.}
\end{figure}
```

But I need an example where I can use subcaption for each figure.

If I use the following code

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Images/ProposedMethod/distance.eps}
            \caption{Distance table for pixel $P_1$}
            \label{distancetable}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line) dilatedcannyedge
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Images/ProposedMethod/detlaE.eps}
            \caption{$\Delta E_{Lab}$-values}
            \label{deltaE}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line) dilatedcannyedge
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Images/ProposedMethod/replacedE.eps}                       \caption{Replaced values for $\Delta E_{Lab}$}
            \label{zeroones}
    \end{subfigure}%bb=0 0 263 198, scale=.2
    \caption{Transformation of matrix values to construct VCD region.}
    \label{vcdregionconstructionsteps}
 \end{figure}
```

with \usepackage{graphicx, subfigure} then it shows me subfigure.sty could not found

Comment: Hi! Have you checked to have that package correctly installed?

Comment: how to check whether a package is correctly installed or not. How to install a package manually.

Comment: Specify your operating system and your tex-latex distribution, otherwise it is difficult to answer...